# ros_arduino_bridge fighting me every step of the way, Raspberry Pi, Hydro, Wheezy

Tags: ros, ros-arduino-bridge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been trying to avoid asking what I'm hoping has an obvious answer, but after 30 hours of struggling with this, it's time to ask the experts.

I've installed ROS (Hydro) on an Raspberry PI.  It seems to have gone as well as could be expected.  I can start roscore, etc.

I've already modified the arduino firmware to do what I wanted (simple encoder, different h-bridge) and it seems to be working from the serial monitor.

However, when I try to launch `ros_arduino_bridge`, I get the following:

```
ERROR:  cannot launch node of type [ros_arduino_python/arduino_node.py]: can't locate node [arduino_node.py] in package [ros_arduino_python]
```

I'm a total ros and python newb, and linux is not far behind.  I know enough to be dangerous.

ROS lives (I think) in the directory `~/ros_catkin_ws`.

Google isn't helping.  I've been through fuerte from an image for the pi, groovy from an image, indigo from repository, and now hydro from repository.

Help?

Thanks,

Ed

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199559/ros_arduino_bridge-fighting-me-every-step-of-the-way,-raspberry-pi,-hydro,-wheezy/) by [emccarron72](https://answers.ros.org/users/21125/emccarron72/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-12-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ERROR: cannot launch node of type [ros_arduino_python/arduino_node.py]: can't locate node [arduino_node.py] in package [ros_arduino_python]

I'm by no means an RPI wizard, but have you made sure you've got the `ros_arduino_python` package installed on your RPI? If so, check that it has the `arduino_node.py` Python script in there somewhere. That is basically what the error is telling you: it cannot find the requested executable (in this case a Python script) in the package specified (in this case `ros_arduino_python`).

Finally, make sure you've sourced the appropriate `setup.bash`. If you have the `ros_arduino_bridge` packages in `~/catkin_ws`, then you should, after `catkin_make`-ing, source `~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash`. If you fail to do this, ROS won't be able to find the packages in your catkin workspace.

If you installed `ros_arduino_bridge` using Debians, then sourcing the normal `setup.bash` in `/opt/ros/DISTRO/` should work for you.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-12-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [emccarron72](https://answers.ros.org/users/21125/emccarron72/) on 2014-12-16**:
That moved me along a step -- thanks!  Up next:  Figuring out why this install seems to have skipped so many things...

Off to experiment!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-12-16**:
Nice. Please use comments next time for these things: answers are really just for answers to the question. I've changed your's into a comment.